WinForms: Reference to UserControl returns null, Forms designer adds bad code to InitializeComponent method
In this class library, there are several UserControls that get loaded and unloaded from a container Panel depending on what functionality is required. These UserControls contain docked panels that contain other controls, including a custom UserControl named NumericUC (basically a fancy number picker). In this case, the containing control is named StandSitUC.
The StandSitUC constructor is typical, but the code for the Load event throws a NullReferenceException at runtime:
// StandSitUC.cs

public partial class StandSitUC : BaseControl
{
    public StandSitUC()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void StandSitUC_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DrawPic(numStand.Value); //Exception on this line, numStand is null
    }    
    ...
}

Using the debugger, when InitializeComponent returns back to the constructor, numStand is null. I was at a loss how this could happen, when it compiled successfully. Then I looked at the Designer.cs file, and realized the Form designer is adding some nasty code to InitializeComponent that is causing this exception.
// StandSitUC.Designer.cs

partial class StandSitUC
{
    // components and Dispose code ...

    #region Component Designer generated code

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        NumericUC numStand; // Forms designer added this crazy line to InitializeComponent
        numStand = new NumericUC();
        // .. The rest of InitializeComponent code
    }

    #endregion

    private Panel panel1;
    private Button btnStand;
    private Label label3;
    private PictureBox picPreview;
    NumericUC numStand;
}

Here you can see insidious this problem is. The designer normally declares the control variables outside of InitializeComponent method. But in this case, another instance of NumericUC is declared INSIDE InitializeComponent, and this new declaration takes precedence over the class-level variable, which remains null, resulting in runtime NullReferenceException(s).
In order to run, I have to manually remove this inner declaration, save, compile, then everything runs as expected. I tried restarting VS, logging out and back in, and rebooting, but this erroneous behavior still happens.
I'm using VS 2022 version 17.8.5, and this is a net-8.0 project. This appears to be a bug in the Forms designer, but it should never declare any variables inside InitializeComponent, only at the class level. I searched for an answer here, even tried ChatGPT, but nothing seemed to available about this mischievous bug. It doesn't happen all the time, and it only happens to my NumericUC control, not to any standard controls.
I hope this helps somebody, because I spent way too much time spinning my wheels on this one. If anyone knows how to send a bug report to MS Form designer team, let me know below.

How did you add  numStand to the form?

Have you edited the designer file by hand? Do you show the actual code? The designer uses typically full qualified names it will use System.Windows.Forms.Panel for example not Panel as you show.

When you look in the designer at the properties of your usercontrol instance is GenerateMember set to "false"? Then that is your problem.

Could not replicate the problem completely with my VS version(17.8.7 LTSC). When you have the somewhat conflicting setting of GenerateMember=false and Modifiers=true, so wanting a public non existent Member and you didn't have edited the designer file by hand then this might actually be some sort of bug.

@MatthewWatson I added the control to the form normally, plop and drop, or copy and paste.

@Ralf I didn't edit the designer file by hand, until it started having this problem. numStand has GenerateMember = false and Modifier = Private, all the other controls have GenerateMember = true and Modifier = Private. I'm not sure this has anything to do with what I'm seeing but it's worth a look.

You want a member so GenerateMember should be true. Why you had a local variable and a member at the same time is then suspicious.

IF GenerateMember = false, then you're asking not to create the Control's instance
